# How to switch between Fragments in default Android Studio Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a Problem with switching Fragments in the default Navigation Drawer

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
package flo.nawigator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "HILFE:" +
                    " An der oberen linken Ecke, findest Du Drei Striche mit dem sich ein Menü öffnen lässt", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment;
        if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.Experimente) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_formeln) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return true;
}
```

}

ContentMain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView android:text="@string/TextViewIntro" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elegantTextHeight="false"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material"
    android:id="@+id/TextViewIntro"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/TextViewIntro"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/mainFrame"></FrameLayout>
```

BlankFragment.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
package flo.nawigator;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fraglayoutv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, null);

    fragbtn1 = (Button) fraglayoutv.findViewById(R.id.buttonfrag1);
    fragbtn1.setOnClickListener(this);

    return fraglayoutv;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonfrag1: {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button gedrückt!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a BlankFragment! How do I Switch to it with Android Navigation Drawer

MainActivity.xml

```
<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

fragment_blank.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="flo.nawigator.BlankFragment"
android:id="@+id/fragmentgalerie">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/galeriefragtext"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Okay!"
    android:id="@+id/buttonfrag1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="217dp" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle navigation view item clicks here.
int id = item.getItemId();


Fragment fragment;




    if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.Experimente) {

   BlankFragment bnlfrgmnt = new BlankFragment();
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.mainFrame, bnlfrgmnt).commit();
  //do similar for other navigation drawer items to display other fragments.




    } else if (id == R.id.nav_formeln) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks but now it says: cannot resolve method ´add (int, flo.nawigator.BlankFragment)´

Comment: you have to pass tow parameters 1)id of the container where you want to display your fragment(must be a framelayout in your mainactivity xml file) & 2) fragment that you want to display i.e in your case pass BlankFragment. or paste your mainactivity xml il hep you

Comment: I have this Framelayout container in Content_Main.xml

Comment: I have added my mainactivity to my Question

Comment: same  cannot resolve method ´add (int, flo.nawigator.BlankFragment)´

Comment: ok got it. this is because you are using native fragment support `app.Fragment`. now what you have to do is in your activity imports change `android.app.Fragment` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: umm seems messy.add all complete files with imports

Comment: oh ok should i upload my projectfolder ?

Comment: BlankFragment.java and fragment_blank.xml? i have uploaded both

Comment: need your fragments as well

Comment: i have added BlankFragment,java with Imports

Comment: change `android.app.Fragment` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in your blankfragment.

Comment: ok i have, but now i have the problem that the Fragment will be created over the mainactivity :-) i hope you understand what i mean

Comment: try different approaches,my solutions were for your posted problems,good luck :)

Comment: Sorry Florian, but I really think you should practice the basics of Android, ie. Activity and fragment handling, even java programming from the sounds of it.

Comment: pls answer to my question

Comment: Florian that is the whole point of the drawer. Selecting which view (read fragment) that should be displayed. The activity should not contain UI. This brings me back to the fact that you should read up on the material before asking questions. Especially when you keep on going like this in the comments.

Comment: and you can accept my answer also if it helped you.!!

Comment: farhan thanks for the answer but i have a another question how to switch to a fragment without Fragment will be created over the mainactivity